# Secure Alternative to "wget --mirror"

Tags: ssh, backup, wget

I'm looking for a secure alternative to doing something like this,

```
wget --mirror --preserve-permissions --directory-prefix=/hdd2/website-backups --exclude-directories=special,stats --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=pass ftp://ftp.domain.com
```

It's executed via cron.

The "--mirror" switch in that is important to me.

Comment: Try to ask this on SuperUser or ServerFault, they might provide better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `rsync`?  (I've never tried it with FTP before, but I'd expect that something could be done.  Definitely works with SFTP/SSH.)

Comment: I did end up going with rsync. The manpage told me just about everything I needed to know, though I ended up having to specify the location of my keys with the "-i" (eye) flag.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "secure" here--you mean you'd like support for SFTP or FTPS?

If so, you could use [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)--but it doesn't do the recursive mirroring on its own; you'll need a script to do that.

Or there are other similar tools--here's a [comparison chart](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html) where you might find one that fits the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

echo ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com | wget -i -

or use .netrc to store passwords

or don't use wget?